# gVim gets shorter on each start with lazyredraw and showtabline=2

Tags: vim, gvim

In my `vimrc`, I have the following:

```
set lazyredraw
set showtabline=2
```

With both these options set, every time I start gVim, the window is a couple lines shorter than it should be. Even if I use `set lines=999` in `vimrc`, it still ends up not filling the screen vertically. It also doesn't matter what order these commands are in.

If I remove either one from `vimrc` and set it manually after gVim has opened, it works as expected.

I've tried using autocmds on the following events: `GUIEnter`, `VimEnter`, `BufWinEnter`, `BufEnter`, `BufNew`, `BufAdd`, `BufCreate`, `FileType`. In each case, the command either didn't run or had the same effect as before.

Vim version: `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10 ...)`

Edit: Still having the issue with `VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18 ...)`. Should also note that this is on Linux.

How can I have both these options (preferably in both Vim an gVim) set from the start?

Comment: How about upgrading to a newer Vim version first? Vim 7.4 is from 2013 and _very_ outdated. It should be possible to install the latest version 8.1; if you can't find a proper package for your distribution (for Windows, check the binaries from the [Cream project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cream/files/Vim/)), it's also not very difficult to [compile](https://www.vim.org/download.php) (e.g. from the GitHub sources) on Linux.

Comment: Cream is not updated anymore, for windows use either https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer or https://tuxproject.de/projects/vim/

Comment: @IngoKarkat, I'm sure the sysadmins are getting tired of my requests for less ancient software at this point... Though I was able to compile it from source (`VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Oct 23 2019 14:22:57)`). Still has the same issue though.